# Playwright Javascript skip fill selector in Google Form

Tags: javascript, testing, playwright

I use Playwright framework on JS to autofill unknow Google form (which means i dont know Xpath to specify the answer, i just know to question. In my situation, form ask about address, name, size, phone number).

```
const { webkit } = require('playwright');
const URL = 'https://forms.gle/B4r6qZKdyxZCApTWA';
    (async () => {
        const browser = await webkit.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(URL);
        await page.fill('input:below(:has-text("Họ và tên"))','name');
        await page.fill('input:below(:has-text("Số điện thoại"))','phone number');
        await page.fill('input:below(:has-text("Địa chỉ"))','Address');
        await page.fill('input:below(:has-text("CMND"))','id');
        await page.fill('input:below(:has-text("Game"))','LOL');
        await page.pause();
        await browser.close();
    })();
```

URL: https://forms.gle/B4r6qZKdyxZCApTWA

The name and number field is fine but in the address field, things get mess up. It skip and jump to the id field and fill 'address'->'LOL'->'id'

Answer (score 0):

The answer field of Google Form has 2 kind: input and textarea. I just need to change it. But any better way to do more "general" to fit that kind of GForm?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).